# Why does Action Listener stop my program from continuously increment/decrement a number?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I am trying to write a simple counter program that creates a window with increment/decrement buttons to add/subtract one to a number. My problem is that the program only works after one click. I'm trying to get it to keep functioning after multiple clicks. Why does action listener prevent multiple clicks?

Example:

User types 5. Clicks '+' button. Result displays 6.
If user clicks again, nothing will happen.

Desired function:

user types 5. Clicks '+' button 5 times. Result should display 10.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class CounterTestDemo4 extends JFrame
{
// Create Buttons and fields
private JButton jbtAdd = new JButton("+");
private JButton jbtSub = new JButton("-");
private JTextField jtfNumber1 = new JTextField(8);
private JTextField jtfResponse = new JTextField(8);

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    JFrame frame = new CounterTestDemo4();
    frame.setTitle("Counter Test");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }


public CounterTestDemo4() 
{
    //Create Panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(new JLabel("Enter Number:"));
    panel.add(jtfNumber1);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Result:"));
    panel.add(jtfResponse);
    panel.add(jbtAdd);
    panel.add(jbtSub);
    add(panel);
    BtnListener listener = new BtnListener();
    jbtAdd.addActionListener(listener);
    jbtSub.addActionListener(listener);
}

class JtfListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     int x = Integer.parseInt(jtfNumber1.getText());
    }
}

 class BtnListener implements ActionListener 
{
    @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
 int int1 = Integer.parseInt(jtfNumber1.getText());
 if(e.getSource().equals(jbtAdd))
  {
    int1++;
  jtfResponse.setText(String.valueOf(int1));
  }

 else if( e.getSource().equals(jbtSub) )
 {
    int1--;
    jtfResponse.setText(String.valueOf(int1));
//end if
}//end else if statement
}//end action performed
}//end BtnListner     
}//end CounterTestDemo4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the number from one JTextField and changing another, but you never get the changed number. Suggestion: don't get the number from any JTextField within your ActionListener. Instead, create an int variable and store the number there in the variable. Use the text fields for display only. The only exception is I suppose if you want to set the number from a JTextField, then set the int field inside of that listener, but after that, use the int field.

Then get rid of jtfResponse:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CounterTestDemo4 extends JFrame {
   private JButton jbtAdd = new JButton("+");
   private JButton jbtSub = new JButton("-");
   private JTextField jtfNumber1 = new JTextField(8);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new CounterTestDemo4();
            frame.setTitle("Counter Test");
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });

   }

   public CounterTestDemo4() {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(new JLabel("Enter Number:"));
      panel.add(jtfNumber1);
      panel.add(new JLabel("Result:"));
      panel.add(jbtAdd);
      panel.add(jbtSub);
      add(panel);
      BtnListener listener = new BtnListener();
      jbtAdd.addActionListener(listener);
      jbtSub.addActionListener(listener);
   }

   class BtnListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         int int1;
         try {
            int1 = Integer.parseInt(jtfNumber1.getText());
            if (e.getSource().equals(jbtAdd)) {
               int1++;
               jtfNumber1.setText(String.valueOf(int1));
            }

            else if (e.getSource().equals(jbtSub)) {
               int1--;
               jtfNumber1.setText(String.valueOf(int1));
            }
         } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jtfNumber1,
                  "Please enter a number in the text field",
                  "Text Field Without Number", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            jtfNumber1.selectAll();
            jtfNumber1.requestFocusInWindow();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your exception is correct, my purpose is to, "set the number from a JTextField," but have I not already set the int field inside of the listener with the line of code: 'int x = Integer.parseInt(jtfNumber1.getText());' ?

Comment: Mind my low level programming skills! Thank you that was very helpful!!